# Magento : Advance Search Result as Per Attribute Value

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, search, catalogsearch

In my magento search form, there is two attribute (qty, price_each). It's  working fine. I want to show exact result with selected attribute value.

Example : if qty value is 100 and price_each range is 200 to 500 then only  product should show qty is equal or greater than 100 and price 200 to 500.

Currently it shows products whose attribute value is 100 and 200 to 500 since this has 100 as well. I have changed search type mode from LIKE to FULLTEXT but both of mode are giving same result for me.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Dhiren can you reply me. if u understand my query

Comment: this is magento default search functionality, you need to customized code for this. Which filter same collection.

Comment: i know its default feature i have to customize. how to customize this function as per my requirement can you reply me.